# wicket (1.5) - Load different JS for development/deployment

Tags: wicket

I want to have something like the following.

```
<head>
   <% if deployment == true %>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <% else %>
   <script src="js/lib/ref/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
   <% endif %>       
</head>
```

How can I do this in wicket?

Update:

Sorry, I was simplifying. Actually I want to include this just before the close body tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your WebPage class implement the IHeaderContributer interface.

Then your class can override the following method

```
public void renderHeader(IHeaderResponse response) {
    if (deployment) {
        response.renderJavascriptReference("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js");
    }
    else {
        response.renderJavascriptReference("js/lib/ref/jquery-1.6.2.js");
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the appropriate method is `Application.get().getConfigurationType();`

Comment: Hmm, ok I was simplifying. Actually these will go just before the end of the body. I assume this will change the method I need to use?

Comment: Thanks jbrookover.
@Alistair: Is there a problem putting these script definitions in the head section? That's really where they should be placed.

Comment: Best practice is to include external script files just before the close body tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143486/unobtrusive-javascript-script-at-the-top-or-the-bottom-of-the-html-code . Basically in some older browsers this is the difference between users getting something to look at while your JS is loading as opposed to a blank screen. I think there are some performance benefits as well.

Comment: @Alistair you can use a wicket:id on a script tag, add a `WebmarkupContainer` and then modify the `src` attribute, via `onComponentTag` or an `AttributeModifier` based on the Application configuration.