# Random Text on Refresh

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a simple text change on refresh:

```
<strong>Title</strong>
<p id="myQuote">Slogan</p>
```

And the "Slogan" part changes on refresh:

```
var myQuotes = new Array();
myQuotes[0] = "To be or not to be";
myQuotes[1] = "The only thing we have to fear is fear itself";
myQuotes[2] = "Give me liberty or give me death";

var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
```

Comment: Did you ensure jQuery is imported and your code is called in a dom ready callback ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: Works for me: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/BsoGH

Comment: You can't select DOM elements until the DOM is loaded; wrap your `$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);` inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`.

Comment: Do I have to have jQuery for this to work?

Comment: Yes...you have $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);

Comment: I addded jQuery to my site and it all works...
I feel dumb xD
Thanks!

Comment: No Problem.  Don't forget to select an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is jQuery is not loaded....

```
if (jQuery) {  
    alert('jQuery is loaded'); 
} else {
    alert('not loaded');
}
```

Then check if you are getting a value from the random function.

```
var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

alert(myQuotes[myRandom]); //Add this to your code

$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't select or manipulate DOM elements until the DOM is loaded.

Wrap your `$('#myQuote').html` call inside a [`$(document).ready(function() { ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), as demonstated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hn6fL/1/).

Alternatively, put your `<script>` tag at the bottom of your `<body>` so it loads after the rest of the DOM. (See further discussion of your load-time options in [Unobtrusive JavaScript: <script> at the top or the bottom of the HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143486/unobtrusive-javascript-script-at-the-top-or-the-bottom-of-the-html-code).)

Comment: Actually you can: http://jsfiddle.net/Hn6fL/2/ you just need to run the code after the specific elements you're targeting are loaded.

Comment: Did you edit my fiddle or make your own with my code? The load-time drop down must be set to `no wrap (head)` or else it gets wrapped anyway by jsfiddle. Here is a non-working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T3htp/

Comment: Are you saying that the code gets wrapped even if you select no wrap (body)?

Comment: Nope! In that case it gets placed at the bottom of the `<body>`, as you suggested in your alternative (which I've added to my answer). I only said "or else it gets wrapped" since that's the jsfiddle default; the no-wrap-body option also does not wrap (as the name suggests).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following to avoid using jQuery in your script

http://jsfiddle.net/TYEGh/

```
$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
```

with

```
document.getElementById('myQuote').innerHTML= myQuotes[myRandom];
```