# how to hide child ul on parent ul mouseout

Tags: jquery, html

i am creating a menu using UN order list tag and jquery

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul
    {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana;
        font-size: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    ul#menu > li
    {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    ul#menu li ul
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
    ul li a
    {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
        background: #2C5463;
        margin-left: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center;
    }

    ul li a:hover
    {
        background: #617F8A;
    }
    /* ul li:hover ul
    {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }
    li:hover li
    {
        font-size: 13px;
    }*/
    li:hover a
    {
        background: #617F8A;
    }
    li:hover li a:hover
    {
        background: #2C5463;
    }
</style>
```

this is the jquery plugin link which i have used

```
http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
```

**this is the jquery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#menu li").mouseover(function () {
            $(".submenu").stop().slideDown();
        });
    });

    $("#menu").mouseout(function () {
        $(".submenu").hide();
    }); 
</script>
```

**here is the html**

```
<div id="linkbar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li style="margin-left: 2px;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="trademarks.html" >Trademarks</a></li>
                <li><a href="Patents.html" >Patents</a></li>
                <li><a href="copyright.html">Copy Right</a></li>
                <li><a href="design registration.html" >Design Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="iso9001.html">ISO 9001</a></li>
                <li><a href="roc.html">Company Formation</a></li>
                <li><a href="importexpertcode.html">Import Export Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop establishment.html">Shop Extablishment</a></li>
                <li><a href="tax Duties.html">Tax- Duties</a></li>
                <li><a href="patnershipworks.html">Partnership Works</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a> </li>
        <li><a href="application status.html">Application Status</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when i hover the mouse on ul menu it show the child menu
 but when it mouseout it does not hide the child ul ! what is wrong with it please help

*please suggest if there is any website to download simple jquery menus*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5fmkt/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li:has('ul')").hover(function () {
        $(".submenu").stop().slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(".submenu").hide();
    });
});
```

or

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5fmkt/1)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").hover(function () {
        $(".submenu").stop().slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(".submenu").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you aren't binding your `mouseout` function on document ready, so `#menu` doesn't exist when you bind the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").mouseover(function () {
        $(".submenu").stop().slideDown();
    });

    $("#menu").mouseout(function () {
        $(".submenu").hide();
    }); 
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle showing your code working](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/6XTHg/). [Here is one with the code as you submitted it.](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/6XTHg/1/)

---

It's also worth noting the other alternative, which is not to use `$(document).ready()` at all. If you place your `<script>` element at the bottom of the `body` element, you don't need to wait for the `ready` event. So the following would also work:

```
<!-- at the end of the body element -->
    <script>
        $("#menu li").mouseover(function () {
            $(".submenu").stop().slideDown();
        });

        $("#menu").mouseout(function () {
            $(".submenu").hide();
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `$(document).ready`. Put your scripts at the bottom.

Comment: @kzh That's an option. It's not compulsory.

Comment: There [are](http://stackoverflow.com/a/816596/143739) plenty [of good](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6026730/143739) reasons to [put your scripts at the bottom](http://thanpol.as/javascript/you-dont-need-dom-ready/).

Comment: I'm not arguing with you. ;-) I'm just adding some more information for other readers, as you did when you commented that it is an option and not compulsory.

Comment: @kzh What I actually meant was, "I'm not disagreeing with you." To which end, see my edit!